# Evalute this integral using Green's Thereom

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Let C be the boundary of the half-annulus

$$1\leq(x^2+y^2)\leq4$$ where $$x\le0$$ 
  in the xy plane, traversed in the positive direction.

Evaluate  : $ \displaystyle \int_{c}(7\cosh^3(7x)-2y^3) dx - (3x^2+\sinh^4(5y)) dy$

I really have no idea where to start, could you please show the full working out if possible.

Note: We are working with parameterization, so I am looking for a method using that approach?

Comment: try [Green's theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green's_theorem)

Comment: @experimentX I am not sure how to start, are you able start me off please?

Comment: Do you perhaps mean "where $x\ge0$ in the $xy$-plane"? Or perhaps $x\le 0$?

Comment: @experimentX Thankyou for notifying me. I have fixed the mistake. Ok, so my next step would be to parameterize it so $y^3=8sin^3(t)$ and $3x^2=4cos^2(t)$ is that correct? If so, now how would I parameterize the inside of cosh and sinh?

Comment: @experimentX oh but $x\leq0$ so $x=-2^2cos^2(t)$ ? and if $$1\leq(x^2+y^2)\leq4$$ $y$ must equal 2?

Comment: @CameronBuie Sorry I've mistaken you for experimentX. I have fixed it now, I mean $x\leq0$

Comment: @experimentX I really have no idea. Could you please perform the working out for this question? From there I believe I can get a good base on how to answer these questions.

Comment: @experimentX The title may have confused you because I worded it wrong? The question is exactly how it is asked in my workbook now. Does that make sense?

Comment: @experimentX I would prefer green's theorem since we are going to learn that. But I don't know how to parameterize it? May you please show the working out for it? Seeing the working out for this question would give me a good base to do the rest of the questions

Comment: Start by looking up Green's Theorem and writing down exactly what it says for this problem. Study examples in yur tex and work each example out yourself without copying the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Green's theorem you can evaluate the integral as 
\begin{align*}
 & \; \; \; \;\int_{c}(7\cosh^3(7x)-2y^3) dx - (3x^2+\sinh^4(5y)) dy\\ 
 &= \iint_R \left( \frac{\partial }{\partial x } \left( - (3x^2+\sinh^4(5y))\right)   - \frac{\partial }{\partial y } \left( (7\cosh^3(7x)-2y^3)\right)\right) dx dy\\ 
 &= \iint_R (-6x + 6y^2) dx dy
\end{align*}

Here is a picture of region
[image]
\begin{align*}
\iint_R f(x,y) dx dy  &= \int_{-2}^{-1}\left( \int_0^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}f(x,y) dy + \int_{-\sqrt{4-x^2}}^0f(x,y) dy \right)+\\ 
 & \int_{-1}^{0}\left( \int_{\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}f(x,y) dy + \int_{-\sqrt{4-x^2}}^{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}f(x,y) dy \right)
\end{align*}

I think you can evaluate those integrals.

---

Also you can parametrize your path as in given picture and evaluate the line integral along those paths.

[image]

Comment: Wow, you have made that so much clearer than what it was before. It's actually not that hard at all thanks to you :). So can I just simply integrate $\int \int_R (-6x+6y^2)dxdy$ using polar coordinates? So $x=rcos(\theta)$,$y=rsin(\theta)$,$1\leq{r}\leq{2},  \frac{pi}{2}\leq{\theta}\leq{\frac{3\pi}{2}} $ ?

Comment: @daniella_H yes you can do that too. I forgot that we can use polar coordinates :((

Comment: And lastly, if I was to integrate the last step, what would my f(x,y) be?

Comment: @daniella_H $f(x,y) = -6x+6y^2$ that we got from Green's theorem. I wrote $f(x,y)$ it was easy to write it. I think polar coordinates is much easier. You don't have to evaluate those 4 integrals that I wrote in cartesian coordinates.

Comment: Oh! I understand this now. Thankyou so much for your help, patience and the effort you put in that post. I hope to be as good as you in Maths one day. It feels so good understanding it :))

Comment: @daniella_H you are welcome ... this is just to compensate those senseless comments I made without really trying which I found it to be wrong.